# Error when using translate ((UNICODE_TO_KANJISJIS) for Tilde character in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

I get the following error when I run the query:
sel  TRANSLATE(EMP_NAME USING UNICODE_TO_KANJISJIS) from TMP.EMP_NAME

Error:
The string contains an untranslatable character

Looks like the tilde character cannot be translate to KANJISJIS.
Is there a way to translate tilde character to KANJISJIS?

Comment: There is no tilde character in standard SJIS. Single-byte x'7E' maps to U+203E overbar. You can potentially use OTRANSLATE to replace the tilde with some other character prior to the TRANSLATE USING Unicode_to_KanjiSJIS.